# How does the Stripe API update customer email?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am having difficulty getting the Stripe API to update the customer email.  When a user is logged in, there is a form to update their email address.  The email address is updated in my database table, but I cannot get the Stripe API to update the customer.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
if (isset($customerid)) {
        try {
            $cu = \Stripe\Customer::update(
                $customer_id,
                [
                    'email' => $_SESSION['email'],
                ]
            );

            $output = "<p>Success!</p>";
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

            // Use the variable $error to save any errors
            // To be displayed to the customer later in the page
            $body = $e->getJsonBody();
            $err = $body['error'];
            $error = $err['message'];

            $output = "Error: $error";
        }
        // Add additional error handling here as needed
    }
```

$customerid comes from my database, and the error routine is pasted from my card update code.

Here is the request POST body from the logs:

```
{
  "email": {
    "0": "myemail@mydomain.com"
  }
}
```

I am getting a fatal error when the script runs:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: Invalid string: {:"0"=>"myemail@mydomain.com"}
```

and the following from the logs:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid string: {:"0"=>"myemail@mydomain.com"}",
    "param": "email",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

---

Is this what the php code should look like per Marcin?  Obviously I'm pretty much a noob.

```
if (isset($customerid)) {
        try {
            $cu = \Stripe\Customer::update(
                $customer_id,
                [
                    "email": "myemail@mydomain.com",
                ]
            );

            $output = "<p>Success!</p>";
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {

            // Use the variable $error to save any errors
            // To be displayed to the customer later in the page
            $body = $e->getJsonBody();
            $err = $body['error'];
            $error = $err['message'];

            $output = "Error: $error";
        }
        // Add additional error handling here as needed
    }
```

The way I did it at first was from the API reference and I tried to mimic their example:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

\Stripe\Customer::update(
  'cus_ElRYM0KexefrGt',
  [
    'metadata' => ['order_id' => '6735'],
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Error message is pretty self explanatory here. You pass JSON object which then is converted to string as `{:"0"=>"myemail@mydomain.com"}`. This is not a valid email syntax so you see the error. You must just pass email address alone:

```
  "email": "myemail@mydomain.com"
```

exactly as [documented](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update):

> email optional
>
> Customer’s email address. It’s displayed alongside the customer in
>   your dashboard and can be useful for searching and tracking. This may
>   be up to 512 characters. This can be unset by updating the value to
>   null and then saving.

Comment: Thanks.  Please see updated code above and please make comments/suggestions.  I'm still having trouble getting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    \Stripe\Customer::update(
        $sc_customer_id,
        [
            'email' => $newemail,
        ]
    );
```